# Port forward server independently and on different DNS domain

Tags: networking, router, dns, port-forwarding

I am currently working on setting up a minecraft server for me and my friends. However, I already have multiple servers port forwarded through a DNS server, and I want the minecraft server to be port forwarded independently on a different DNS domain. I want to keep the existing dyndns.com DNS with it's servers, and port forward the minecraft server on a new DNS domain which would only contain the minecraft server.

My router only allows multiple DNS servers for IVP6, but my network runs on IPV4. Also, the multiple DNS servers on IPV6 would contain all of the servers, with no option to split servers between DNS services.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may wish to clarify your question with additional details regarding your current configuration since, as it stands, it is arguably confusing what problems you are having. Particularly, you may wish to add what specific DNS service(s) you are using, why you might want to use another service, and why IPV6 is a necessity/hindrance.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Added clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port forwarding works *only* with IP addresses – it is completely independent from DNS, and *"port forwarded through a DNS server"* makes no sense at all.

In other words: If you have multiple DNS domains which resolve to the same IP address, all of them will have the same TCP & UDP ports available. The only way to avoid that in general is to use two different IP addresses.

You can, however, make a Minecraft-only domain using SRV records:

1. Remove all IP addresses (A/AAAA) records from the new domain.
2. Add a SRV record on `_minecraft._tcp.<newdomain>`, pointing to your old dyndns domain.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the minecraft server to be port forwarded independently on a different DNS domain.

As pointed out by @grawity, port forwarding is independent of DNS/domains, including dynamic DNS.

Technically, all DNS does is map a domain name to an IP address. It contains no port information whatsoever. This means that you can have 1 or 100 domains pointing to your public IP and they can all send traffic to the same ports. This includes if you are using some additional features of a given web service to reroute ports for a domain it handles.

> I want to keep the existing dyndns.com DNS with it's servers, and port forward the minecraft server on a new DNS domain which would only contain the minecraft server.

All you should need to do is set up the second service similarly to the first (aim it at your public IP address, assuming no ISP NAT is involved). If you need to adjust port routing for that service via its web interface, as noted, it should not interfere with the first domain's services at all. If your port forwarding is done in your router, simply forward the correct ports.

> My router only allows multiple DNS servers for IVP6, but my network runs on IPV4. Also, the multiple DNS servers on IPV6 would contain all of the servers, with no option to split servers between DNS services.

This bit still confuses me slightly but I don't believe this would be an issue. I am guessing the router has an interface to automatically keep its public IP in sync with your dynamic DNS domain. While it's true that you couldn't use this with a second domain, it shouldn't be a deal breaker. To keep the IP for the Minecraft server up to date, you could either run the normal dynamic DNS client on the server itself or (worse case scenario) keep the IP manually updated if it changed.